# Regex to Match Multiple Matches in Same Line With Optional Text Between

Tags: regex

I'm fairy novice at RegEx, but I've written a regular expression that handles most of my use cases:

[`(\d*\.?\-?\d+)\s*\|\s*\[Link\]\(*https:\/\/redd\.it\/(\w+)\/*`](https://regex101.com/r/H53QK1/2),

...except one. I know this could probably be improved to be less greedy and I'm open to suggestions.

The gist of the RegEx is to capture a pair:

- Any digit (whole number or decimal, and I included hyphens between numbers) before a standardized URL (https://redd.it/**capturethisnext**). Almost all cases have a "|" at the end of the digit. Some lines can have multiple digits that would be paired with a separate standardized URL.
- The ending ID of the standardized URL: https://redd.it/**capturethisnext**. Some lines can have multiple URLs in them that would need to be matched with their preceding digit.

The 3rd line in the link should match on **0** and the part of the link saying **0isamatchandthisisamatch**. I didn't know how to make all the text between the digit and the URL optional, but I assume adding this logic could simplify things.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should make the `[Link]` part optional, and some of the delimiting characters:

[`(\d+(?:[.-]\d+)?)[|\]\s]*(?:\[Link\]\()?https:\/\/redd\.it\/(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/H53QK1/4)

Comment: This will match the whole part and not only the `capturethisnext`.

Comment: This achieves what I'm looking for actually with 2 capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your list to match against:

```
1|[Link](https://redd.it/1match)|4.5|[Link](https://redd.it/2match)
3000|[Link](https://redd.it/only1)|[9.5](https//otherlink.com)
0|https://redd.it/0isamatchandthisisamatch
Episode 1 | [Link](https://redd.it/spacesexist)
Episode 1-20 | [Link](https://redd.it/rangeofnumbers)
```

It is normally best to make your RegEx as simple as possible.

And here is my RegEx String:

```
(?<=\/)(\w+)((?=\))|\n)
```

The first group looks before and matches the `/` before the matching string and the last group matches either a `)` or a line break.

**Edit:**

```
(?<=redd\.it\/)(\w+)((?=\))|\n)
```

Here if you have `https//otherlink.com/abc` in your data.

Or here if you are sure that you only want to match the first word after `redd.it/`:

```
(?<=redd\.it\/)(\w+)

https://redd.it/willmatchthis/butnotthis
```

Comment: Yes, the 3 line is different than the others by design. More likely it was an old format. Do you have a link to the RegEx in action?

Comment: EDIT: Looks like the newline at the end doesn't like when there isn't a closing parentheses - https://regex101.com/r/UJP41A/1

Comment: @alpacafondue Normally I use https://regexr.com/ but I haven't found any sharing option. I copied my RegEx to your posted website and there it does work as well, without any problem.

Comment: @alpacafondue Thats because there is no line break at the end of the "file".

Comment: @alpacafondue I edited my answer and added two additional solutions. The last one should fit the best to all your current requirements. Please be more specific with your examples.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to incorporate `(\d*\.?\-?\d+)\s*\|\s*`? I would also like to capture the digit prior to the URL. As for examples, there aren't too many more than this. The links are pretty standardized. This appears to work: `(\d*\.?\-?\d+)\s*\|\s*.+(?<=redd\.it\/)(\w+)`

Comment: @alpacafondue Please provide an example for each line and how the output should look like. Do you want to output `11match` and `4.52match` for line one?